# Request ajax per button jquery, twitter bootstrap

Tags: jquery, ajax

How to get an ajax response for a clicked button?

**The HTML part:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success ccomment" rel="popover" data-original-title="Comment" value="12">click</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success ccomment" rel="popover" data-original-title="Comment" value="460">click</button>
```

and the **jquery script**:

```
<script type='text/javascript' language='javascript'>
$('.ccomment').click(function(){

    var ccomment_val = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/getcomment/'+ccomment_val,
        type:'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(output){

            $('.ccomment').popover({
                content: output,
                html: true,
                placement: 'right',
                trigger: 'click'
            });
        } 
    });   

});

</script>
```

I just want to bind a valid ajax response with a specific button. Right now, the output is related to the button clicked as first.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not 100% sure what your trying to achieve as your explanation isn't great. But i have spotted what i believe to be a potential issue in the script, assuming it does what i think it does. So here's the solution (i hope).

underneath the line `var ccoment_val....` add:

`var self = $(this);`

this will add a reference to the clicked button that you can then use in the ajax response. So once you have added that line, change: `$('.ccomment').popover(` in the ajax success function to: `self.popover(`

That should solve what i think is what your trying to say is the problem, if not, i apologise.

Comment: Thank you Lee, that was it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('button[value="'+ccomment_val+'"]').popover({
    content: output,
    html: true,
    placement: 'right',
    trigger: 'click'

  });
```

you can change your popover binding like this. hope it will work

Comment: Thanks muneebShabbir, it is always good to know some more explanations and solutions.

Comment: this selector will select the button which contains the value attribute equal to value retrieved in `ccomment_val` so if your buttons have unique values then this code will work fine